# Perform edit and delete operation in ext.net gird panel

Tags: c#, ext.net

How to perform edit and delete in ext.net gridpanel? and changes should be reflected in sql server database.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you tried _anything_ so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: yes  since morning i am trying and try currently...

Comment: hello guys please help me out..

Comment: @user2298848 some code would be nice. also... did you read ext.net documentation/examples? and. a single line does not really show anything like: "i am trying"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a record, please use a Store's remove method.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#...-method-remove

To edit a record, you should choose a way of editing. There is a few in Ext.NET.
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/...s/CellEditing/
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Plugins/RowEditor/
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/...Column/Editor/
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/...n/Over_Editor/
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/...mn/Pin_Editor/

Regarding saving to server. Please investigate the examples of the saving functionality.
http://examples.ext.net/#/search/saving
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Update/AutoSave/
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Update/Batch/
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/...SqlDataSource/

The [source](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?24538).